# Can't delete a file from a client after uploading it to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, file-upload

I'm using asp:FileUpload control to upload a file to the server. Nothing fancy there, just

```
FileUploadId.Save();
```

File gets uploaded successfully, and everything is fine until I try to delete that file on the CLIENT. I get a good-old "File is being used by another person or program" message.

How do I make sure that file is not being accessed on the client after it's been uploaded?

#### EDIT

deleting the file has nothing to do with the application. i'm just trying to delete the file manually since i don't need it any more.

#### EDIT2

closing the browser fixed the problem ... any ideas?

Comment: If the problem is on the client, then it probably has nothing to do with asp.net/.net/c#. Instead it might be a problem of the web browser you are using. Do you have this problem with every browser or just a specific one?

Comment: both FF and IE case the problem. how do i troubleshoot it?

Comment: So: there is a bug in the browser(s). Not sure that we can help with that...

Comment: Install Process Explorer from Sysinternals. After startup select the spyglass and enter the name of your file. Now you'll get a list of all process that have a handle to this file. Maybe this can help. Link to Process Explorer:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem happens both in IE and FF: could it be that the file is locked by some AntiVirus software?

Comment: If I remember correctly I had the same problem on a machine with AVG installed...

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be the file can be locked by the aspnet process even after uploading. Once you close the IE, the aspnet process release the file

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to delete the file at the client? Unless you're hosting in `WebBrowser`, or using something like an ActiveX control, you only have javascript at the client - and that doesn't provide random file access.

So: what is the full setup here?

Comment: I'm deleting it MANUALLY, deleting part has nothing to do with the APP. i have the file (abc.zip), i upload it to the server, i delete abc.zip locally, since i don't need it any more ... oops ... can't delete

Comment: So... at best there is a bug in the browser. Not sure that we can help with that...

Answer (score 0):

A thought. It may not be the file upload that is causing the problem. As the surrounding code isn't posted it's difficult to tell, but, for example, do you have a Zip manager object of some kind that you're not disposing of?