# Can't delete a file from a client after uploading it to the server after uploading multiple files via webkit directory html input

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I am uploading a directory using html input with webkitdirectory. I send the files in a form to the .net controller to parse and store the data to the DB. This whole process works fine however, after you upload the files, you are no longer able to delete the file from your local machine until you close the google chrome instance (where the app is running).

I can not figure out for the life of me why this is. I tried disposing all of the files uploaded, closing all the files. I even removed all of the file reading logic and just made the front end hit the controller upload method and do nothing to the files.

I downloaded Process Explorer to see what is happening and here is what I found:

When the controller is hit, there are 2 processes created by chrome for each file that is in the directory (I dont know why 3 are created). After the method is done running, there is ONE process for each file uploaded running. Since there are processes running for the files AFTER the upload, on my local machine I am unable to delete or rename the file, however I am able to edit it for some reason.

I know that the httpPostedFileBase is also contained in Request.Files from the ajax request, I am not sure if that is the issue, as I am also passing the files into a view model. I even took out the view model and only processed the files from Request.Files, and still had the same issue.

I came across a post that had a similar issue as mine with no real solution or fix for their issue. [Post here][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717878/cant-delete-a-file-from-a-client-after-uploading-it-to-the-server]

```html
$("input:file").change(function () {

        var allFiles = $('input[name="allFilesInput"]').prop('files');

        // Quantity of files uploaded...

        var fileCount = allFiles.length;

        if (fileCount > 0) {

            var form = $("#Form");

            var formData = new FormData(form[0]); // data within the form

            // Append all files to formData to send to backend...
            for (var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {

                formData.append(allFiles[i].name, allFiles[i]);

            }

            if ($(form).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Controller/UploadFiles",
                    data: formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                       // Does stuff
                    },
                    processData: false,
                    cache: true,
                    success: function (partialViewResult) {
                 // Does stuff
                   }
                });

                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<form id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <input id="allFilesInput" name="allFilesInput" type="file" hidden webkitdirectory/>
 </form>
```

```html
        [HttpPost]

       public ActionResult UploadFiles(MyViewModel model)

        {
          // Empty upload no processing done, chrome still creates processes.
        }

 

 

    public class MyViewModel : ViewModel
    {

        public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> AllPayrollFiles { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How large is the file? Do you clear the file input after the file upload succeeds?

Comment: The file is only one character for debugging purposes. I have tried clearing the file input after a success setting fileInput.val(''), this did not help anything for me.